# VBscript from Java opens (unexpected) settings dialog

Tags: java, vbscript

I have a short VB that opens a browser window. The script is started from a Java process, by the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` command with wscript.exe as interpreter. When I start the script from the prompt it runs as expected, but from my Java process it opens up the "Windows Script Host Settings" dialog (instead of opening the browser window). Is this some kind of security measure?

My Java app runs in Java 1.6 and the Windows versions I've tested is Windows 7 and Windows 2003 terminal server session.

Comment: depends of how do you create `String` parameters inside `exec(".....")`

Comment: It looks like this: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wscript.exe", new String[] { scriptPath, webPageToOpen })

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the script just by the scriptname itself so without defining the VM, if necessary you can define one of the two VM's as the default VM (see wscript.exe /?)
If this doesn't help, try the following

run regedit, navigate to `Hkey_local_machine \software \microsoft \windowsNT \currentversion \winlogon`
Here there is a userinit registry double click on that. In the Value data field there will b something like `C:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe, C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscript.exe` 
Delete the `C:\WINDOWS\system32\wscript.exe` part so that the field only has C`:\WINDOWS\system32\userinit.exe`,
Click ok and close the registry editor and then restart windows